# Lucas Kanade dense optical flow

Tags: opencv

Can OpenCV be used to calculate dense optical flow using Lucas Kanade method? I am aware of function in gpu/ocl module that can do that (gpu::PyrLKOpticalFlow::dense), but is there non-gpu equivalent of that function?

I'm also aware of Farneback and TV L1, but I need LK / pyramidal LK for my research.

Answer (score 3):

No. Actually there is no good dense optical flow extraction method. I'm facing the same problem (particle advection on optical flow, right?)

There is a function that evaluates optical flow with Farneback method [[1](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#calcopticalflowfarneback)], but it gives me bad results. It does not use ocl nor gpu.

You may try with `phaseCorrelate` to extract it with a shift based algorithm. I've used this method. When I will upload it to github I'll give you the link.

[EDIT]

**Here is the code. I've decided to separate the phase correlation algorithm from the whole project, to make it more simple to understand:
https://github.com/MatteoRagni/OpticalFlow**
Please star it, if you intend to use it.

Comment: I actually ended up using TV-L1 method for calculating dense optical flow. OpenCV has a good implementation of it. It gives better results than Farneback, but at considerable performance cost.

Comment: @ barak. I'll do it before the end of the month and I'll publish here the link to the project. If you like and you consider to use it could you star it, please?

Comment: @Srđan the method I've mentioned has also a really considerable performance cost

Comment: hey, i'm just curious, but imho you'll deserve the star already for publishing any attempts at this !

Answer (score 2):

You can find the OpenCV non-gpu video analysis functionality documentation [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html)

There is an implementation of the sparse iterative Lucas-Kanade method with pyramids (specifically from [this paper](http://robots.stanford.edu/cs223b04/algo_tracking.pdf)). The function is called `calcOpticalFlowPyrLK`, and you build the associated pyramid(s) via `buildOpticalFlowPyramid`. Note however that it does specify that it's for sparse feature sets, so I don't know how much of a difference that'll make for you if you need dense optical flow.