# find optical flow for each pixel opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, feature-extraction, opticalflow

I use the following  functions as a base of my tracking algorithm.

//1. detect the features
what i mean, this function extract the only good features,

```
cv::goodFeaturesToTrack(gray_prev, // the image 
features,   // the output detected features
max_count,  // the maximum number of features 
qlevel,     // quality level
minDist);   // min distance between two features
```

// 2. track features

```
cv::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(
gray_prev, gray, // 2 consecutive images
points_prev, // input point positions in first im
points_cur, // output point positions in the 2nd
status,    // tracking success
err);      // tracking error
```

`cv::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK` takes vector of points from the previous image as input, and returns appropriate points on the next image.
Suppose I want to calculate the opical flow for each pixle instead of good features

in the other meaning, start to calculate the optical flow from(1,1 ) to (m,n)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opencv tracking using optical flow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701276/opencv-tracking-using-optical-flow)

Comment: @RogerRowland No, that question is not the same.

Comment: May I also suggest this? It is called phase correlation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16718241/lucas-kanade-dense-optical-flow/21007222#21007222

Answer (score 7, accepted):

cv::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK does sparse OF, ie from feature points, if you want it for each pixel, use

[calcOpticalFlowFarneback](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#calcopticalflowfarneback) .

Computes a dense optical flow (using the Gunnar Farneback’s algorithm).